# Second click macro to delete data entered on first click?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is a ridiculously easy thing to do, but I'm not well versed in VBA yet. What I have is a form control button "Yes" that when clicked puts the number "10" into the cell next to it:

```
Sub YesButton_Click()
    Range ("L6").Value="10"
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is be able to click the same button a second time and have it make the cell next to it blank - the one where we just put the 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub YesButton_Click()
If Range("l6") = "" Then
Range("L6").Value = "10"
Else
Range("L6").Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```